# How does AbstractQueuedSynchronizer in JDK14 ensure memory visibility when using setPrevRelaxed?

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

In method [`acquire`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk-14%2B36/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/locks/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java#L635), `node.prev` is updated by `node.setPrevRelaxed(t)`.

It actually calls `unsafe.putReference` which does not ensure the visibility.

```java
final void setPrevRelaxed(Node p) {      // for off-queue assignment
   U.putReference(this, PREV, p);
}
```

How dose it ensure the visibility of `node.prev`?

Answer (score 0):

In Java, the happened before semantic ensure that visibility.

For example, `node.setPrevRelaxed(t)` is used in two place, the first one is in the enqueue method

```java
final void enqueue(Node node) {
        if (node != null) {
            for (;;) {
                Node t = tail;
                node.setPrevRelaxed(t);        // avoid unnecessary fence
                if (t == null)                 // initialize
                    tryInitializeHead();
                else if (casTail(t, node)) {
                    t.next = node;
                    if (t.status < 0)          // wake up to clean link
                        LockSupport.unpark(node.waiter);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

`node != null` iff euqueue is call in Condition object which ensure this object has acquired a lock.

Another place is in acquire method

```java
...
node.waiter = current;
                Node t = tail;
                node.setPrevRelaxed(t);         // avoid unnecessary fence
                if (t == null)
                    tryInitializeHead();
                else if (!casTail(t, node))
                    node.setPrevRelaxed(null);  // back out
                else
                    t.next = node;
...
```

In theses two case, the node.prev will be seen after the lock is released or casTail  successfully.